# Column name defaults overridden, but generated queries still refer to undefined column

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, code-first

I have a LINQ query (that involves a join) that fails with an exception that I know is coming out of the naming conventions and assumptions that Entity Framework makes, but I cannot find out where that setting is or how to shut it off.  The exception I get is:

```
ORA-00904: \"Extent2\".\"Client_PermanentClientId\": invalid identifier"
```

There is no such column in any of our tables, it is a combination of a table name (`Client`) and a column (`PermanentClientId`), but I have overridden (or so I thought) all of the column name defaults with `.HasColumnName()`.

Can anyone tell me where I go in EF to turn off the creation of this name, or why it's spinning this up?

Client Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Paychex.IP.Common.Validation;


namespace Paychex.IP.Common.IPEntities.Models
{
    [Serializable]
    [Table("CLIENT")]
    public class Client : IPEntity
    {
        #region Entity properties and validation attributes

        [Key]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Client: PermanentClientId cannot be zero")]
        public int PermanentClientId { get; set; }

        public int AssociateNumber { get; set; }

        public int ClientNumber { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Client: ClientName is limited to 50 characters")]
        public string ClientName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Client: Address1 is limited to 30 characters")]
        public string Address1 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Client: Address2 is limited to 30 characters")]
        public string Address2 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(24, ErrorMessage = "Client: City is limited to 24 characters")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [StringLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Client: State is limited to 2 characters")]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Client: ZipCode is limited to 10 characters")]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        [StringLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Client: Country is limited to 3 characters")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [StringLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Client: ClientType is limited to 3 characters")]
        public string ClientType { get; set; }

        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Client: DoingBusinessAs is limited to 30 characters")]
        public string DoingBusinessAs { get; set; }

        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Client: Contact is limited to 30 characters")]
        public string Contact { get; set; }

        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Client: PhoneNumber is limited to 20 characters")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Client: Extension is limited to 10 characters")]
        public string Extension { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Client: FaxNumber is limited to 20 characters")]
        public string FaxNumber { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Client: FaxExtension is limited to 10 characters")]
        public string FaxExtension { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Client: Email is limited to 50 characters")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public int NextEmployeeNumber { get; set; }

        [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Client: PayFrequency is limited to 15 characters")]
        public string PayFrequency { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Client: EmployeeSort is limited to 10 characters")]
        public string EmployeeSort { get; set; }

        [DbBoolValidation("Client: UseDivisions is not a valid DbBool")]
        public string UseDivisions { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Client: ClientAccessType is limited to 10 characters")]
        public string ClientAccessType { get; set; }

        public string AutopayWageId { get; set; }

        public string Fein { get; set; }

        [DbBoolValidation("Client: HrModule is not a valid DbBool")]
        public string HrModule { get; set; }

        public int BankCode { get; set; }

        public int AchDays { get; set; }

        public string AchCollect { get; set; }

        [DbBoolValidation("Client: Updated is not a valid DbBool")]
        public string Updated { get; set; }

        [DbBoolValidation("Client: IatFlag is not a valid DbBool")]
        public string IatFlag { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Client: OriginalEmail is limited to 50 characters")]
        public string OriginalEmail { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ClientWage> Wages { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ClientDivision> Divisions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ClientDepartment> Departments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ClientJob> Jobs { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ClientDeduction> Deductions { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region IValidatableObject interface implementation

        // No custom validation for now

        #endregion

        #region IValidationHelper interface implementation

        public override void PopulateContext(ValidationContext context)
        {
            context.Items.Clear();
            context.Items.Add("PermanentClientId", PermanentClientId);
            context.Items.Add("ClientName", ClientName);
            context.Items.Add("Address1", Address1);
            context.Items.Add("Address2", Address2);
            context.Items.Add("City", City);
            context.Items.Add("State", State);
            context.Items.Add("ZipCode", ZipCode);
            context.Items.Add("Country", Country);
            context.Items.Add("ClientType", ClientType);
            context.Items.Add("DoingBusinessAs", DoingBusinessAs);
            context.Items.Add("Contact", Contact);
            context.Items.Add("PhoneNumber", PhoneNumber);
            context.Items.Add("Extension", Extension);
            context.Items.Add("FaxNumber", FaxNumber);
            context.Items.Add("FaxExtension", FaxExtension);
            context.Items.Add("Email", Email);
            context.Items.Add("PayFrequency", PayFrequency);
            context.Items.Add("EmployeeSort", EmployeeSort);
            context.Items.Add("UseDivisions", UseDivisions);
            context.Items.Add("ClientAccessType", ClientAccessType);
            context.Items.Add("HrModule", HrModule);
            context.Items.Add("Updated", Updated);
            context.Items.Add("IatFlag", IatFlag);
            context.Items.Add("OriginalEmail", OriginalEmail);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

The Client_map class:

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

namespace Paychex.IP.Common.IPEntities.Models.Mappings
{
    public class Client_map : EntityTypeConfiguration<Client>
    {
        public Client_map()
        {
            this.ToTable("CLIENT", "INSTANTPAY");

            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.PermanentClientId);

            // Column Properties

            this.Property(t => t.PermanentClientId)
                .HasColumnName("PCLIENT_ID");

            this.Property(t => t.AssociateNumber)
                .HasColumnName("ASSOCIATE_NO");

            this.Property(t => t.ClientNumber)
                .HasColumnName("CLIENT_NO");

            this.Property(t => t.ClientName)
                .HasColumnName("CLIENT_NAME");

            this.Property(t => t.Address1)
                .HasColumnName("ADDRESS1");

            this.Property(t => t.Address2)
                .HasColumnName("ADDRESS2");

            this.Property(t => t.City)
                .HasColumnName("CITY");

            this.Property(t => t.State)
                .HasColumnName("STATE");

            this.Property(t => t.ZipCode)
                .HasColumnName("ZIP");

            this.Property(t => t.Country)
                .HasColumnName("COUNTRY");

            this.Property(t => t.ClientType)
                .HasColumnName("CLIENT_TYPE");

            this.Property(t => t.DoingBusinessAs)
                .HasColumnName("DOING_BUSINESS_AS");

            this.Property(t => t.Contact)
                .HasColumnName("CONTACT");

            this.Property(t => t.PhoneNumber)
                .HasColumnName("PHONE");

            this.Property(t => t.Extension)
                .HasColumnName("EXTENSION");

            this.Property(t => t.FaxNumber)
                .HasColumnName("FAX");

            this.Property(t => t.FaxExtension)
                .HasColumnName("FAX_EXTENSION");

            this.Property(t => t.Email)
                .HasColumnName("EMAIL");

            this.Property(t => t.NextEmployeeNumber)
                .HasColumnName("NEXTEMP");

            this.Property(t => t.PayFrequency)
                .HasColumnName("PAY_FREQ");

            this.Property(t => t.EmployeeSort)
                .HasColumnName("EMPSORT");

            this.Property(t => t.UseDivisions)
                .HasColumnName("DIVUSE");

            this.Property(t => t.ClientAccessType)
                .HasColumnName("CLIENT_ACCESS_TYPE");

            this.Property(t => t.AutopayWageId)
                .HasColumnName("AUTOPAY_WAGE_ID");

            this.Property(t => t.Fein)
                .HasColumnName("FEIN");

            this.Property(t => t.HrModule)
                .HasColumnName("HR_MODULE");

            this.Property(t => t.BankCode)
                .HasColumnName("BANK_CODE");

            this.Property(t => t.AchDays)
                .HasColumnName("ACH_DAYS");

            this.Property(t => t.AchCollect)
                .HasColumnName("ACH_COLLECT");

            this.Property(t => t.Updated)
                .HasColumnName("UPDATED");

            this.Property(t => t.IatFlag)
                .HasColumnName("IAT_FLAG");

            this.Property(t => t.OriginalEmail)
                .HasColumnName("ORIG_EMAIL");
        }
    }
}
```

In the DbContext-derived classes, we override the OnModelCreating method and use the map classes to define each table.  Here is one of the related classes map file:

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;


namespace Paychex.IP.Common.IPEntities.Models.Mappings
{
    public class ClientDeduction_map : EntityTypeConfiguration<ClientDeduction>
    {
        public ClientDeduction_map()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => new { t.PermanentClientId, t.DeductionId });

            this.ToTable("CLIENTDEDUCTION", "INSTANTPAY");

            // Column Properties

            this.Property(t => t.PermanentClientId)
                .HasColumnName("PCLIENT_ID")
                .IsRequired();

            this.Property(t => t.DeductionId)
                .HasColumnName("DEDUCTION_ID")
                .IsRequired();

            this.Property(t => t.Active)
                .HasColumnName("ACTIVE")
                .HasMaxLength(1);

            this.Property(t => t.AllowOnLevy)
                .HasColumnName("ALLOW_ON_LEVY")
                .HasMaxLength(1);

            this.Property(t => t.AnnualLimit)
                .HasColumnName("ANNUAL_LIMIT")
                .HasPrecision(9, 2);

            this.Property(t => t.Frequency)
                .HasColumnName("FREQUENCY");

            this.Property(t => t.LimitPerPay)
                .HasColumnName("LIMIT_PER_PAY")
                .HasPrecision(5, 2);

            this.Property(t => t.Description)
                .HasColumnName("DESCRIPTION")
                .HasMaxLength(20);

            this.Property(t => t.PaceId)
                .HasColumnName("PACE_ID");

            this.Property(t => t.Priority)
                .HasColumnName("PRIORITY");

            this.Property(t => t.RateType)
                .HasColumnName("RATE_TYPE")
                .HasMaxLength(10);

            this.Property(t => t.ShortDescription)
                .HasColumnName("SHORTDESC")
                .HasMaxLength(5);

            this.Property(t => t.VendorId)
                .HasColumnName("VENDOR_ID")
                .HasMaxLength(8);

            this.HasRequired(t => t.Client)
                .WithMany(w => w.Deductions)
                .HasForeignKey(t => new { t.PermanentClientId });

        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the OnModelCreating override:

```
       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ColumnTypeCasingConvention>();

        var mbClient = new Client_map();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(mbClient);

        var mbActivePayrolls = new ActivePayroll_map();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(mbActivePayrolls);

        var mbPaychecks = new Paycheck_map();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(mbPaychecks);

        var mbPaychecktax = new PaycheckTax_map();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(mbPaychecktax);

        var mbPaycheckwage = new PaycheckWage_map();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(mbPaycheckwage);

        var mbPaycheckDeduction = new PaycheckDeduction_map();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(mbPaycheckDeduction);

        var mbStates= new State_map();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(mbStates);

        var mbClientHeaderSchedule = new ClientScheduleHeader_map();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(mbClientHeaderSchedule);

        var mbClientDepartment = new ClientDepartment_map();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(mbClientDepartment);

        var mbClientDivision = new ClientDivision_map();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(mbClientDivision);

        var mbClientWage = new ClientWage_map();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(mbClientWage);

        var mbViewEmployeeList = new ViewEmployeeList_map();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(mbViewEmployeeList);


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the `Client` class?

Comment: @Stijn "I know there is a setting I need to override, but I cannot find it" is not a good question title. I understand that the title before your edit could use improvement, but I don't know if I'd call this improvement.

Comment: One area to investigate is whether there are any navigation properties that aren't mapped explicitly and require additional columns in the actual database, they're easy to overlook. But without seeing the relevant classes, it's hard to make this concrete enough to be a useful answer.

Comment: @hvd I just removed the tags from the title and added code formatting to two words while I was editing. Feel free to edit the title to something better.